# chkdsk stops on 23 %

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I have problems with my Windows System. Sometimes, there is a user login window and I can log in, but sometimes it freezes just before the login window. When I manage to enter Windows, it usually freezes when I try to open any application; so I decided to do `chkdsk` but it is 15 minutes until it is on 23%. I can see that the number of scanned files is growing (step 4/5) **but is it normal that it takes so much time**?

My system is an HP NX7400, and the hard drive is 300 GB

Comment: Yes it is, there is nothing to worry about

Comment: How long have you left it to run for? I've seen `chkdsk` run for several hours. The size has a direct bearing on how long `chkdsk` runs.

Comment: Although this is true, if the progress stops in one place for a while and if you are experiencing odd hangs and pauses, this is - in my experience - very often caused by a disk with errors on it.

Comment: +1 No argument there from me. There is probably something wrong with the disk, but `chkdsk` should at least finish before attempting something different.

Comment: True enough Randolph.

Comment: I've personally seen cases where chkdsk had to be left running overnight in order to finish checking and repairs a large hard disk -- but eventually it did.

Comment: Running time for CHKDSK is O(number of files) not O(size of disk). If the number of files scanned is increasing, GOOD, things are progressing. You're probably in the part of CHKDSK where it's verifying that directory entries and file records are consistent.  Worst case has two seeks/file, so figure 100 files/second. If you have 100K files, that's 16 minutes and I bet you have more than 100K files.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not normal.

Almost certainly there is an error on that part of the disk. This is not that uncommon with the cheap, volume-made disks we all use.

The disk is very unlikely to get better on its own I'm afraid. Depending on the size of the disk, it may be better to just replace it.

If, however, you want to try to improve matters you would be well advised to pay for a copy of [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com). This tool can recover many disk errors and often returns seemingly faulty disks to full health if the error was just from some transient issue rather than a physical fault. Spinrite is not free or even especially cheap (US$90 I think) though it is a stable and mature product that I've used a number of times to recover from issues that would otherwise have been disastrous. Read up on what people have done with it over the years to see how good it is.

Comment: SpinRite is a last resort, due to the thrashing it induces on a drive with bad sectors. I'd advise against it, and simply copy the data off  the drive and buy a new hard drive for that $90. (Disclosure: I am a paying customer of SpinRite.)

Comment: I agree @RandolphWest, just thought I'd mention it anyway. If the disk is a big one, it might be worth it. I usually only use it to recover important data. It's also worth running from time to time on disks to prevent issues.

Comment: I can't agree with its use as a maintenance tool. In my experience, backups to another device, with periodic testing, is more reliable than what SpinRite does to a disk. Last resort only, in my opinion. That said, we are allowed to disagree, and I mean no disrespect.

Comment: Backups certainly trump recovery any day ;)  I don't think testing helps - the research by Google a while back seems to back this up. It is not uncommon to get minor disk glitches that are easily reset by Spinrite before they turn into problems. And I'm only talking maybe once or twice a year at most, not often.  But don't worry, no disrespect taken or given, I'm always interested in other views.

Comment: +1 for your comment. I'm a DBA by trade, and testing backups is my bread and butter :-).

Comment: :) cheers! I'm an IT Technical Architect. Backups are always high on my agenda both for enterprises and individuals (especially for family computing). I'm a fan of CrashPlan because of the low cost and ease of use. Sorry - off topic, I'll shut up now.

Comment: Not sure why I got voted down here - I wish people wouldn't downvote without explaining - how can we improve our answers if we don't know what people think are wrong! Stand up and tell me what is wrong.